# Matlab - handle

Tags: oop, class, matlab, handle

In programming in `Matlab`, if I pass by a statement as follows:

`classdef xyz < handle`

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

This line makes your `xyz` class *inherit* from the `handle` class. The `handle` class allows your object to be passed into other functions by reference. This means that if you have a function`foo(x)` that modifies `x` internally, your `x` will be modified in the caller after the function returns. A good article on this topic can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle.html).

Answer (score 1):

Please read the [manual](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html):

> A handle class constructor returns a handle object that is a reference to the object created. You can assign the handle object to
>   multiple variables or pass it to functions without causing MATLAB to
>   make a copy of the original object. A function that modifies a handle
>   object passed as an input argument does not need to return the object.